# Java Desktop app to pop up websites captcha

Tags: java, popup, captcha

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm quite new to Java and wanting to build a small app to practice etc.

Anyway I want to fill out a form on a site and grab the data.  I have had a look at HtmlUnit and HtmlComponents and think I have most of the design covered.

Something I can't figure out is the site has a single captcha and I want my desktop app to popup a window where I would enter the captcha (manually, I'm not creating a bot).

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman :) He wants to do kinda hack :) I meant

Answer (score 0):

It's possible and in fact [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org) is doing it. It's open source, so you can take a look to its code.

Comment: I did stumble across the JDownloader site just before so I might see if I can understand what they're doing.  Not to sure what the "hack" talk is about??

Comment: Hhmmm I have been going through the JDownloader code for the JAntiCaptcha and for me its quite complex as they seem to be auto solving the captcha but I just want it to pop up

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before JDownloader does this technique quite well. You mentioned the source is rather difficult to understand, so I'll explain the basics of what one would do.

First you would want to create your code that will fill in the form, once the form hits the captcha have it open up a frame that has a spot for an image (which will be the captcha image), a textfield, and a submit button. The submit button should have an action that will send the text from the textfield to the captcha text field in the form.

**Summary:**

1: Create you class that will fill in the form

2: Once it gets to the capthca make it open your 'captcha solving frame'

3: Fill in the text field and create an actionPerformed on the button that will send your string to the textfield in the form

4: Throw in some sort of catch in case you improperly fill in the captcha

On a side note, this would be easier and considerably less verbose if done with Groovy (or a scripting language) rather than Java.